# Client wants a Client Management System

Tags: finance

I have a client of mine that wants a Client Management System.  They want something web based, priced well (free would be amazing) where they can keep track of their clients information, when they've contacted that client and what that client has purchased off of them.
Anyone know of any good sites/systems for this?

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be Sugar CRM:

http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/